# SQL UNION without using the individual column names

Tags: sql-server

I want to take the union of two tables. They both have unequal number of columns and some of them are in common and some are not.

How would i take its union them without using the individual column names (inserting dummy columns in between).

I have to query and take the union of couple of tables and would be testing on different databases, which would have different column names for the same table. 
Hence, i could not use the common way of addressing the individual column names and inserting dummy columns to get the union.

Thanks,
gokul.

Comment: You must indicate the columns if the tables have different columns. WHy do your databases on differnt servers have differnt names? It strikes me that you have a database design porblem nota  query problem. HOw owuld you know what columns you want if you don;t know in advance what the columns are?

Comment: What an Epic Fail.  I want to do a GROUP BY without specifying the columns too.

Comment: My Skyrim alchemy skill is almost leveled to 100. Maybe I can help.

Comment: I think you guys are thinking too literally about a potential solution. Obviously you can't express what he wants directly with a single SQL statement. But you can do what he wants in general.

Answer (score 3):

> How would i take its union them without using the individual column names

You can't.

When using UNION that numbers and types of columns *must* match.

Comment: what i essentially want to do is, not wanting not insert dummy columns. but i do not want to go through each column name as it is impossible to know that in advance..

Comment: @user1489580 - I don't have a better answer for you. As HLGEM [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251532/sql-union-without-using-the-individual-column-names/11251564#comment14787232_11251532), you seem to have a database design problem. If the databases share a schema, why are the column names and numbers different?

Comment: 'impossible to know that in advance' - if it's impossible to know the columns in advance, what are you going to do with the data?

Answer (score 2):

You could synthesize the appropriate `SELECT...UNION...SELECT` statement by inspecting `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` for the two (or more) tables in question.  Armed with the columns, you can build the SQL such that you only include the common columns.

Using T-SQL:

```
SELECT  COLUMN_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'FirstTable'
UNION
SELECT  COLUMN_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'SecondTable'
```

Using C# as an example to describe the logic:

```
List<string> sharedColumnNames = CallTheAforementionedSql();
string unionStatement = string.Format(
  "SELECT [{0}] FROM FirstTable UNION SELECT [{0}] FROM SecondTable",
  string.Join("],[", shareColumnNames.ToArray())
);

var stuff = ExecuteSql(unionStatement);
```

Comment: But how to match up columns from both tables? You'd have to know the column names to match them up anyway.

Comment: I'll make my answer more explicit...

Comment: Not tagged as C#.  However you still could do this in a proc, but it's a complete waste of time.

Comment: That will work, _if_ both tables have columns in the appropriate order.

Comment: `string.Join(",", shareColumnNames.ToArray())` You'd want to wrap the columns in brackets []

Comment: Please note:  "different column names for the same table"

Comment: @DanAndrews I took that to mean that the shape of `FirstTable` would be different based on environment.  Either way, I think asking the server's meta-data would insulate you from that danger; even if you were doing this for the same table across instances.

Comment: Not if the table has spaces, just FYI